# Array Value Not Found Error

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I have the following formula:

ArrayFormula(if(isblank('Form Responses 1'!A2:A)=true," ",BE2:BE&" "&BF2:BF&" ("&BD2:BD&") "&"Order Date: "&TO_TEXT(A2:A)))

I am testing with only 4 rows right now (generated from Google Form (responses)); the first 3 rows work great but the 4th row has the "Array value not found".  I have spent about 2 hours skimming the other responses in the forum but I cannot find why this is happening to the last entered row.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have four rows and start on the second then after three rows the `A` column will be blank, so then the IF condition TRUE, so the result `""` and nothing to concatenate.

Pity users don't realise that for a good answer quickly, tell us **what** you have (with **where** that is) and **what** you want (with **where** to put it) – ***instead of*** “Please fix this”.